# How to get class file from protoc.exe

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, protocol-buffers, javac

I am trying to use protocol buffers for my first time. I am following the tutorial provided by google. The *.proto I make is as follows:

```
    package tutorial;
option java_package = "com.example.tutorial";
option java_outer_classname = "AddressBookProtos";

message Person {
  required string name = 1;
  required int32 id = 2;
  optional string email = 3;

  enum PhoneType {
    MOBILE = 0;
    HOME = 1;
    WORK = 2;
  }

  message PhoneNumber {
    required string number = 1;
    optional PhoneType type = 2 [default = HOME];
  }

  repeated PhoneNumber phone = 4;
}

message AddressBook {
  repeated Person person = 1;
}
```

I then compile it with the following command:

```
protoc -I=../examples --java_out=src/main/java ../examples/addressbook.proto
```

It runs without error and produces addressbook.java. But from what I can tell, I need a *.class so that I can use this in the eclipse environment. I have tried outputting it to a *.jar file with the command:

```
protoc -I=../examples --java_out=src/main/java/addressbook.jar ../examples/addressbook.proto
```

But after importing that jar to a project, eclipse says I need classes. I have also tried compiling it to a class with the command while I am in the examples directory.

```
javac *java
```

It sees the file but returns a ton of lines followed by "100 errors". I understand that I may be completely lost and not even close to the right idea... but any help would be great! Thanks!

oh and here is the code that calls this proto...

```
import com.example.tutorial.AddressBookProtos.AddressBook;
import com.example.tutorial.AddressBookProtos.Person;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;

class ListPeople {
  // Iterates though all people in the AddressBook and prints info about them.
  static void Print(AddressBook addressBook) {
    for (Person person: addressBook.getPersonList()) {
      System.out.println("Person ID: " + person.getId());
      System.out.println("  Name: " + person.getName());
      if (person.hasEmail()) {
        System.out.println("  E-mail address: " + person.getEmail());
      }

      for (Person.PhoneNumber phoneNumber : person.getPhoneList()) {
        switch (phoneNumber.getType()) {
          case MOBILE:
            System.out.print("  Mobile phone #: ");
            break;
          case HOME:
            System.out.print("  Home phone #: ");
            break;
          case WORK:
            System.out.print("  Work phone #: ");
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(phoneNumber.getNumber());
      }
    }
  }

  // Main function:  Reads the entire address book from a file and prints all
  //   the information inside.
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if (args.length != 1) {
      System.err.println("Usage:  ListPeople ADDRESS_BOOK_FILE");
      System.exit(-1);
    }

    // Read the existing address book.
    AddressBook addressBook =
      AddressBook.parseFrom(new FileInputStream(args[0]));

    Print(addressBook);
  }
}
```

THANKS!

[Link to protobuf tutorial I am using!](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/javatutorial.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just include the .java file in your src directory in eclipse. Eclipse will compile it into a .class file.

Comment: WOW! That was all... geez! Thank you so much! I need that!